# Restricting continous character occurence

Tags: spring-mvc

I have to stop the acceptance of name if given with same character multiple times. ex: "daaaaa".  this should not be considered as name

Answer (score 0):

Following is the most naïve way to do it. Just create a validate method which returns true or false.

```
private boolean validate(String str) {
    for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++) {
      if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1)) {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

If you want something in spring then it provides you pattern annotation where you can use regular expression to validate string.

```
@Pattern(regexp="^(?:([A-Za-z])(?!.*\1))*$",message="there should not be any repeating characters")  
private String pass;
```